# How to enumerate all Popup windows?

Tags: popup, win-universal-app

There are many places in our code where we display popup windows which are not attached to a parent. In other words it is

```
var objPopup = new Popup() {
   Child = objControl,
   IsOpen = true
};
```

It is normal to have 2 or 3 popups on the screen simultaneously. Is it possible to enumerate all currently displayed popups? Enumerating all elements from Window.Current.Content using VisualTreeHelper does not help. It returns only elements which are in the logical tree. If a popup is placed on a XAML it will be in the result. If it is instantiated in the code it won't. I need to find all currently displayed popups. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `Popup` doesn't host the Child within itself. The Children of the `Popup` are hosted within `PopupRoot`. You can see it in the `Live Visual Tree`.

You can see the following code:

```cs
TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
text.Text = "Hello";
TextBlock text2 = new TextBlock();
text2.Text = "Hello world";
var objPopup = new Popup()
{
    Child = text,
    IsOpen = true
};
var objPopup2 = new Popup()
{
    Child = text2,
    IsOpen = true
};
```

[image]

From the picture, you can see the `Button` is in the `RootScrollViewer` and the Children of the `Popup` will show in the `PopupRoot` when the `Popup` is displayed.

If you want to enumerate all currently displayed popups, as a workaround you can add `Popup` to the collection.That you can use `foreach` to get all of the `Popup`, then you can use the `Popup.IsOpen` to know if the popups are displayed.

For example:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Popup> popups;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
    text.Text = "Hello";
    TextBlock text2 = new TextBlock();
    text2.Text = "Hello world";
    var objPopup = new Popup()
    {
        Child = text,
        IsOpen = true
    };
    var objPopup2 = new Popup()
    {
        Child = text2,
        IsOpen = true
    };
    objPopup.HorizontalOffset = 100;
    objPopup2.HorizontalOffset = 600;
    popups = new ObservableCollection<Popup>();
    popups.Add(objPopup);
    popups.Add(objPopup);
    foreach (var item in popups)
    {
        if (item.IsOpen == false)
        {
            item.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `VisualTreeHelper` class, specifically the [`GetOpenPopups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getopenpopups) method.

Using it should be pretty easy. Try something like this:

```
var listOfOpenPopups = VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.Current);
```